# aws eb deploy doesn't load environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying symfony project via eb deploy to ec2 instance (aws linux 2). Post deploy migrations scripts works well, but then I try to run symfony command with ec2-user I get an error about wrong database credentials. It is because I have pushed dump .env file with empty values. All my enviroment variables are stored in eb -> configuration -> Environment properties. How to make these variables to be visible to other users to properly execute commands?

I can see these variables as json with:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The EB env variables on Amazon Linux 1 are stored in:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
```

Thus, to load them when you login to the instance you can do the following:

```
source /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
```

To check if they got loaded, you can just execute:

```
env
```

p.s.

For Amazon Linux 2:

```
export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
```

Comment: what about linux2?

Comment: @MartynasTumas In AL2 is different, but your question is about AL1, isn't it? There is no such thing as `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment` in AL2.

Comment: @MartynasTumas I updated the answer to include Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: I'm logged in as ec2-user, and had to sudo the cat to get around permission issues. `export $(sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)`.
Anyone else going out of their minds hitting countless dev-ops issues with rails on elastic beanstalk?

Comment: @Alan Not only rails but every other platform has issues. Most docs and tutorials are for Amazon Linux 1, and hardly any of them can be used for EB based on Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: Hi @Marcin I just run the second command for EB Amazon Linux 2 I got this error: `cat: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env: Permission denied`

Comment: No issues for me when running this "export $..." command in a .sh script within a ```.ebextensions/example.config``` file

Comment: @RabeeaAli this file is owned by root. Try running `sudo -i` then cat it again

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on the same issue, [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-linux2/) documentation shed some light on how to fix permission issues in Amazon Linux 2 although it is not straightforward.

Comment: the link your provided gives a 404 error.

Comment: the link is visible on the wayback machine, however, it might not be up to date if AWS removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Something to note, is that the answer provided by @Marcin will fail if implemented in a deployment script within the .ebextensions or .platform folders on new instance deployments.

In order to properly retrieve the environment variables, and source them to the shell, AWS has an article outlining how this is done:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell/

For future reference, here are the instructions copied from the AWS docs:

Resolution

1. Create a .ebextension file in your application source bundle and include the following:

```
commands:
    setvars:
        command: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.key)=\"\(.value)\""' > /etc/profile.d/sh.local
packages:
    yum:
        jq: []
```

Note: The configuration file in step 1 is called setvars.config.

2. Save the .ebextension file, and then deploy it to your Elastic Beanstalk environment.
3. To test if the variables are being exported, connect to your instance using SSH, and then run the following command. Before testing, close any existing sessions and then reconnect using SSH.
   env | grep VARIABLE_NAME
   Important: For step 3, set VARIABLE_NAME to a variable defined in your environment.

The output shows if your environment variables are set correctly. In the following example output, a variable called RDS_PORT is defined in the Elastic Beanstalk environment.

```
$ env|grep RDS_PORT
RDS_PORT=3306
```

Note: Because you're using the commands on the .ebextension, you can update the sh.local file only with a new deployment. If you add or change a variable in the environment, then you must create a new deployment before the variable is exported to the operating system.

Comment: A word of warning: that AWS article also states:

`Note: Because you're using the commands on the .ebextension, you can update the sh.local file *only* with a new deployment. If you add or change a variable in the environment, then you must create a new deployment before the variable is exported to the operating system.`

Which pretty much makes it useless, as it will only work for deployments and you can't use the EB Console to make changes to your environment variables.

Comment: Yes, so this depends on how you configure your deployments in EB. If you set your deployments and configuration updates to Immutable, it will create new instances each time you deploy, hence, running any script in your .ebextensions folder.